# Function sequence error in Python from pyodbc when getting id of row inserted into MSSQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to add a new auto incremented row in an MSSQL database and read the id value created. When I do the SQL statement runs okay but as soon as I try to query the row from the returned ResultProxy object I get a 'Function sequence error'

I am using SQL Alchemy (pyodbc) to connect to the database and using execute() to run text queries. Running the SQL command via SQL Management Studio works fine.

This is what I am trying;

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
dbstring = "mssql+pyodbc://<SNIPPED>"
engine = create_engine(dbstring)
con = engine.connect()
res = con.execute(text("""INSERT INTO test(v) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES( :v )"""), {"v": 10})

print(res) # This prints <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object>
print(res.first()) # This is the line where things go wrong
```

The final line of code causes the following error;

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Hi adt100, welcome to StackOverflow. I have no idea what is going wrong but I can advice you to add `echo=True` to `create_engine` call so you can see if it mounted the SQL query as you expected

Comment: Thanks for the tip geckos. Doing as you asked shows the INSERT SQL being sent and the final COMMIT line but interestingly doesn't add anything during the last line of the code where the error is occurring.

Comment: isn't `;` ending required? I totally guessing here, I found multiple occurrences of this error in the internet and in very distinct scenarios

Comment: Thanks for looking geckos. Do you mean at the end of the SQL statement? I have tried adding a ';' at the end and still get the same result. The command is executing and the data is being added. It is the read back of the OUTPUT that seems to be failing.

Comment: ~Ohh yeah, what you expect to get from calling `.first()` after an insert?~ I see the `OUTPUT` there. This doesn't see to be very

Comment: I would try `pymssql` driver instead of pyodbc

Comment: @adt100 - Are you using pyodbc 4.0.26?

Comment: Yes Gord. Version 4.0.26

Comment: @adt100 - I was able to reproduce your issue. However, [this works](https://pastebin.com/aujkwaUr) so you may want to [ask on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues) what SQLAlchemy might be doing behind the scenes that the SQL Server ODBC driver apparently doesn't like.

Comment: Hmm. This also seems to work: `res = con.execute(text("""INSERT INTO test(v) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES( :v )""").execution_options(autocommit=False), {"v": 10})`. The `INSERTED.id` value is returned and the insert does indeed remain UNcommitted. We'd have to come up with a way to trigger the commit.

Comment: I do not use OUTPUT, and I'm having same issue here. I did not find any answer good yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `engine.begin()` instead `engine.connect()` like so:

```py
with engine.begin() as con:
    new_id = con.execute(text("""INSERT INTO test(v) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES( :v )"""), {"v": 10}).scalar()
```

Related question: [Get MSSQL autogenerated id from INSERT Statement using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744691/get-mssql-autogenerated-id-from-insert-statement-using-sqlalchemy)